# Can I prompt a user to log in to facebook through a bookmarklet generated div?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, bookmarklet

I'm looking to see some info about my facebook contacts, and I want the info to be overlayed on the currently open website.

Currently, I'm trying to do this via a bookmarklet.

Is it possible for me to overlay a div over the currently open web page and populate it with a functioning facebook login button (if the user is not logged in)? Are there publicly available working examples of something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably not possible to simply embed Facebook within an iframe because Facebook blocks people from embedding their pages within frames or iframes by putting this into the response header, "X-Frame-Options: DENY". This is most likely to prevent click-jacking and similar security exploits.

To test this, enter any page from Facebook into http://savanttools.com/testframe

Facebook has an API which allows you to do many things, but it requires server side code, and can not be done simply with a bookmarklet.

There is also always the brute force method where your server scrapes data from any website you want it to. Then that data could be put into a bookmarklet.

Finally, the same thing could be achieved by writing an add-on or a user script without using a bookmarklet at all.